# Error in Job preferences: "Sorry, something went wrong"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, error-message

When I press Save in my profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/856090 section `Job preferences`, it appears the error message

> Sorry, something went wrong

near the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We updated some libraries and ended up with some conflicts in production that weren't visible in our integration test suite.

A fresh deployment is up, and things should be stable again. Apologies for the inconvenience.